# C# UITypeEditor Dropdown Not Working With Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, contextmenustrip, uitypeeditor

WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO

Hello everyone. I'm trying to make a dropdown inside a property grid. This dropdown for some objects will just place its text inside the property, like a StringConverter. But for other objects, it behaves like a button and will open up other forms or an OpenFileDialog. These forms and OpenFileDialog return a text, which is then put inside the property. I feel like I'm doing this very incorrectly so if there is a better way of doing this. But hopefully there is a simple solution.

WHAT I'VE TRIED

I'm very close. I can get the text to show up on a MessageBox. But I can't seem to put it in the property grid, which is in another form and is protected so I can't shove the value in. The way it works is on the other form, the property grid selected an object, which has an attribute called text.

WHAT I'M DOING NOW

When I click on the dropdown for my text attribute in my property grid. The context menu strip is created, all the click events are on, and then, it returns a value right away. Which is not what I want. I want it to wait for me to click on one of the items inside the context menu, the click events sets the string text, and then, the value returns.

```
public class text-editor: UITypeEditor
{
    string text = "";

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) { return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown; }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
        cms = MakeCms(cms); // adds some ToolStripEditor, & their click events which updates value
        
        ToolStripMenuItem add = new TooStripMenuItem("Add");
        add.Click += new EventHandler(CmsClick); // updates value
        cms.Items.Add(add);

        ToolStripMenuItem remove = new TooStripMenuItem("Remove");
        remove.Click += new EventHandler(CmsClick); // updates value
        cms.Items.Add(remove);
        
        cms.Show(Control.MousePosition);

        if (text != "")
        {
            value = text;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ContextMenuStrip.Show method does not pause the caller and cannot be used here. Create a custom ContextMenuStrip integrated with [IWindowsFormsEditorService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.iwindowsformseditorservice).

```cs
public class TextEditor : UITypeEditor {
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) { return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown; }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        if(editorService != null) {
            MyContextMenuStrip cms = new MyContextMenuStrip(editorService, "Add", "Remove");
            editorService.DropDownControl(cms);
            if(cms.SelectedItem == "Add")
                return "Value When Add";
            else if(cms.SelectedItem == "Remove")
                return "Value When Remove";
        }
        return value;
    }
}
class MyContextMenuStrip : UserControl {
    readonly IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService;
    readonly ListBox listBox;
    public MyContextMenuStrip(IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService, params string[] items) {
        this.editorService = editorService;
        listBox = new ListBox();
        listBox.Items.AddRange(items);
        listBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listBox.MouseClick += ListBox_MouseClick;
        listBox.Parent = this;
    }
    public string SelectedItem => (string)listBox.SelectedItem;
    private void ListBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        if(listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
            Rectangle selectedItemRect = listBox.GetItemRectangle(listBox.SelectedIndex);
            if(selectedItemRect.Contains(e.Location))
                editorService.CloseDropDown();
        }
    }
}
```